# Cannot pass value from form to variable to be posted

Tags: php, html, oop

I want to pass some value from my form to be sent with POST. However, when i use dropdown, it wont detect the value and thus giving me undefined index error for every variable

When i use simple text form to post, it works, but i need to use the dropdown form.

**dropdown for shop code**

```php
<?php $stmt = $shop->readName();
    echo "<select class='form-control name='shop_id'>";
    echo "<option>select shop name</option>";

    while ($row_shop = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row_shop);
        echo "<option value='{$shop_id}'>{$shop_name} </option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

and the post code

```php
if ($_POST) {
  // Set values
  $transaction - > customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
  $transaction - > shop_id = $_POST['shop_id'];
  $transaction - > staff_id = $_POST['staff_id'];

  // create transaction
  if ($transaction - > add()) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Transaction was created.</div>";
  }

  // if unable to create the staff, tell the user
  else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Failed.</div>";
  }
}
```

EDIT : Now the error is gone, but the form simply wont do anything :(
Here's the screenshot of the form
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaWj8.png)

Comment: Can you post screenshoot of the form ?

Comment: What about the rest of the parameters? `customer_id` and `staff_id`?

Comment: the rest of the parameter also gave me an error

Answer (score -1):

Undefined index errors means that you haven't defined `$transaction` as an object, thus when you try to update one of the values (for example `$transaction->customer_id`), PHP will give you an error.

Try defining `$transaction` like so:

```
$transaction = new yourObjectNameHere();
```

Just after the `if($_POST)`.

Comment: i have defined the transaction and the connection, and yet the issue still exist :(